# Worpress plugin - The image map opens an alert before executing the code

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

The image map opens an alert before executing the code.

Hi,I am developing a small plugin to map an image and I am facing the following problem.

I want to click on the area tag to open a modal window, for this I am using the following code :

HTML

```
<img src='image.jpg' usemap='#image_map'>
 <map name='image_map'>
      <area  alt='img' title='img' href='#' coords='561,1121,693,1162' shape='rect' class='imgclick'/>
 </map>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.imgclick').click(function() {

        $('#modal-mapeo').modal('show');
    });
});
```

The problem is that first an alert opens mentioning that the area was clicked and after the alert the modal window opens.

I have tried to block the default href of the area but it didn't work.

Comment: is there an `alert()` somewhere you're not showing with an event handler like `$('.imgclick').click(function()`??

Comment: No alert, even if I remove `$('.imgclick').click(function()`  the alert is executed when the area tag is clicked.

Comment: I would start checking your plugins and disabling them until you find out which one is calling the `alert()` function.  Need more info at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `preventDefault()` statement will solve your problem.
Can you change your code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.imgclick').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        $('#modal-mapeo').modal('show');
    });
});
```

You can read more about preventDefault [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: It doesn't work, I had already tried it, the problem is that the alert opens when I click on the area, even if the href goes to a page, first the alert comes up and then redirects.

If I remove the js to the area it still shows the alert. 

I'm using the code for WordPress, in a normal html page if the solution you mention works.